# Display foreign key columns as link to detail object in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

As explained in [link-in-django-admin-to-foreign-key-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832897/link-in-django-admin-to-foreign-key-object), one can display a ForeignKey field as a link to the admin detail page.

To summarize,

```
class Foo(Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('link_to_bar',)
    def link_to_bar(self, obj):
        link = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:app_bar_change', args=[obj.bar_id])
        return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (link, obj.bar) if obj.bar else None
    link_to_bar.allow_tags = True
```

The question is: can we do it more automatically? For instance, provide to the `FooAdmin` definition a list of foreign key to display as links to detail page:

```
class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_foreign_key_links = ('bar',)
    ...
```

I know that these `ModelAdmin` classes are generated with metaclass programming. Then, it should be possible. What would be a good start to do so?

Answer (score 49):

The solution below uses [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48950925/4411196)
but makes it reusable by all models, avoiding the need to add methods to each admin class.

#### Example Models

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    population = models.IntegerField()

class Career(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    average_salary = models.IntegerField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    career = models.ForeignKey(Career, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### Example Admin

```
# admin.py
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Person


def linkify(field_name):
    """
    Converts a foreign key value into clickable links.
    
    If field_name is 'parent', link text will be str(obj.parent)
    Link will be admin url for the admin url for obj.parent.id:change
    """
    def _linkify(obj):
        linked_obj = getattr(obj, field_name)
        if linked_obj is None:
            return '-'
        app_label = linked_obj._meta.app_label
        model_name = linked_obj._meta.model_name
        view_name = f'admin:{app_label}_{model_name}_change'
        link_url = reverse(view_name, args=[linked_obj.pk])
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', link_url, linked_obj)

    _linkify.short_description = field_name  # Sets column name
    return _linkify



@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "name",
        "age",
        linkify(field_name="country"),
        linkify(field_name="career"),
    ]
```

---

#### Results

Given an App named `app`, and a Person instance `Person(name='Adam' age=20)` with country and carreer foreign key values with ids `123` and `456`,
the list result will be:

```
| Name | Age |                          Country                          |...|
|------|-----|-----------------------------------------------------------|...|
| Adam |  20 | <a href="/admin/app/country/123">Country object(123)</a>  |...|
```

(Continues)

```
|...|                          Career                         |
|---|---------------------------------------------------------|
|...| <a href="/admin/app/career/456">Career object(456)</a>  |
```

Comment: Great function! I'd change `linked_obj.id` by `linked_obj.pk` to deal with custom pks.

Comment: Super helpful! I'd use `c = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)` from `django.contrib.contenttypes.models` instead of the private member `_meta`. Then you can get the app/model name from `c.app_label` and `c.model`.

Comment: raises attribute error if linked_obj is null - to handle nullable fields add `if not linked_obj: return '-'`

Comment: `readonly_fields = (linkify("example"),); exclude = ("example",)` makes it possible to make a read-only field within the admin view of the database object. However, for some reason, I can't do similar by overriding `def get_readonly_fields(self): ...`

Comment: You can add `_linkify.admin_order_field = field_name  # Enables ordering on the field` next to `_linkify.short_description = field_name  # Sets column name` to enable ordering on that field again.

Comment: Is there a way to always linkify foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

A good start would be looking at the source of [`BaseModelAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L97) and [`ModelAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L480). Try to find out how the ModelAdmin generates the default links. 
Extend `ModelAdmin`, add a method to generate links to arbitrary foreign keys and look at how [`ChangeList`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L37) generates the change list.

I would also suggest you use [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) to render the links, which makes `link_to_bar.allow_tags = True` unnecessary:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('link_to_bar', )
    def link_to_bar(self, obj):
        link = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:app_bar_change', args=[obj.bar_id])
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', link, obj.bar) if obj.bar else None
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight respin on the accepted answer. It is not necessarily better, but implements some of the advice in the comments:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html


def linkify(field_name):
    def _linkify(obj):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
        app_label = content_type.app_label
        linked_obj = getattr(obj, field_name)
        linked_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(linked_obj)
        model_name = linked_content_type.model
        view_name = f"admin:{app_label}_{model_name}_change"
        link_url = reverse(view_name, args=[linked_obj.pk])
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', link_url, linked_obj)

    _linkify.short_description = field_name.replace("_", " ").capitalize()
    return _linkify
```

Comment: I get:
'In template /var/work/django/oscar/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grappelli/templates/admin/base.html, error at line 0

'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta''

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62434674/1798234) answer, allowing you to supply an optional alternative short description instead of the supplied `field_name` being used for the column header. And also an optional `label_prop` value to display an alternative property value of the model if so desired

**EDIT**: I've also now updated it to handle ManyToManyFields

```
from typing import Optional

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models import ManyToManyField, ForeignKey, Model
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html

def create_link(linked_obj, app_label: str, label_prop: Optional[str] = None) -> str:
    linked_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(linked_obj)
    model_name = linked_content_type.model
    view_name = f"admin:{app_label}_{model_name}_change"
    link_url = reverse(view_name, args=[linked_obj.pk])
    return "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (link_url, getattr(linked_obj, label_prop) if label_prop else linked_obj)


def linkify(field_name: str, label_prop: Optional[str] = None, short_description: Optional[str] = None, as_html_list: bool = False):
    def _linkify(obj: Model):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
        app_label = content_type.app_label
        field_type = obj._meta.get_field(field_name)
        items = None

        if isinstance(field_type, ManyToManyField):
            items = list(getattr(obj, field_name).all())
        elif isinstance(field_type, ForeignKey):
            items = [getattr(obj, field_name)]
        else:
            print(f'field_name {field_name} is not ManyToManyField or ForeignKey')

        links = [create_link(itm, app_label, label_prop) for itm in items if itm is not None]

        if len(links) > 1:
            if as_html_list:
                html = "<ul>"
                for link in links:
                    html += f'<li>{link}</li>'
                html += "</ul>"
            else:
                html = ", ".join(links)
        else:
            html = links[0]

        return format_html(html)

    _linkify.short_description = [short_description, field_name.replace("_", " ").capitalize()][short_description is None]

    return _linkify
```

Example usage:

**Models**

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    population = models.IntegerField()

class Career(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    average_salary = models.IntegerField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    career = models.ForeignKey(Career, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Admin**

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "name",
        "age",
        linkify(
          field_name="country",
          label_prop="name",
          short_description="Country Name"
        ),
        linkify(field_name="career"),
    ]
```

**Result**

Given the `name` of Adam's country is France.

```
| Name | Age |                     Country Name                         |...|
|------|-----|----------------------------------------------------------|...|
| Adam |  20 | <a href="/admin/app/country/123">France</a>              |...|
```

**It's also worth noting...**

...the `linkify` function can also be used along side the [display decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display)

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "name",
        "age",
        "sortable_country_link",
        linkify(field_name="career"),
    ]

    @admin.display(description='Country Name', ordering='country__name')
    def sortable_country_link(self, obj):
        return linkify(field_name='country', label_prop='name')(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted it even more automatic, so I can easily list all fields, possibly excluding some, while displaying foreign keys as links. So, building on the `linkify` function in the [reply of @gtalarico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53092940/2725810), I defined:

```py
def linkified_list_display(model, exclude = []):
    return [linkify(field_name=f.name) if f.many_to_one else f.name 
            for f in model._meta.fields if f.name not in exclude]
```

Now I can simply do:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = linkified_list_display(
        MyModel, exclude = ['not_to_list_1', 'not_to_list_2'])
```