# Django-admin linked column issue

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28834051/3592078) answer I wanted to add a linked column to my admin page,

```
class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'link_to_question', 'time_created', 'time_updated', 'created_by', 'down_vote', 'up_vote')

    def link_to_question(self, obj):
        link = urlresolvers.reverse("admin:QnA_question_change",
                                    args=[obj.question.id])  # model name has to be lowercase
        text = obj.question.__str__
        str = format_html("{}", text)

        return mark_safe(u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (link, str))

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
```

but what I get in return is this:

```
<bound method Entry.__str__ of <Question: This is a question about technology?>>
```

I only want the "This is a question ..." part shown in my admin.

**Sidenote:**
when I use something like obj.question.text instead of a function it works smoothly.

Comment: should be `text = obj.question.__str__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear why you are using `format_html` then passing the result to `mark_safe`. You should be able to do it in one step with [`format_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html). This has the advantage of escaping `text`, in case a use has inserted malicious content.

```
    link = urlresolvers.reverse(...)
    text = obj.question
    link_str = format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', link, text)
```

To call the `__str__` method you need to call it with `obj.question.__str__()`. However, it's more pythonic to call `str(obj.question)` rather than `obj.question.__str__()`. In this case, I don't think you need to use `str()` at all, since you are using `format_html`.

Comment: ohhhh! that's it! I'm not calling the function :)))) 

Thanks man, your help is really appreciated!
I was just messing around with format_html and mark_safe to find out what they do :))

in my __str__ function I trim the text to 150chars, thats why I'm using it here.

Comment: and could you please fix your answer for anyone who might read this later?
it should be like this:
str = format_html("<a href=\"{}\">{}</a>", link, text)

Comment: My point is you don't have to explicitly call `str()` or `__str__`. It will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

just set the allow_tags = True property of the method.

```
class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'link_to_question', 'time_created',    'time_updated', 'created_by', 'down_vote', 'up_vote')

    def link_to_question(self, obj):
        link = urlresolvers.reverse("admin:QnA_question_change",
                                args=[obj.question.id])  # model name has to be lowercase

        return u'<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(link, obj.question)

    link_to_question.short_description = u'Link'
    link_to_question.allow_tags = True
```