# How to display foreign key as a link to a model in another app in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, hyperlink, foreign-keys, django-admin

I'm using `Django==2.1.5`. And I've gone through the similar questions to what is in my title but couldn't find a working solution due the similarity in model names and their respective field names used in foreign key relationships and also the models in those use cases were in the same app, so it confused me.

I've a model `Order` in my `Shopping_cart` app:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I've another model `Profile` in my `accounts` app:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In the admin of `Order` I've displayed the respective user for the particular order like so:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'date_ordered', 'is_ordered', 'buyer_email')
    def buyer_email(self, instance):
        return instance.owner.user.email
```

I want to display this `buyer_email` in `list_display` of order as a link, right now it's just a text. One thing to note here is `Profile` has again `OneToOneField` with `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. I want the link to go to the `Profile` admin change view or if we can send it to the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` user admin change view like the way they're trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832897/link-in-django-admin-to-foreign-key-object) , it would be of much help!

Comment: Why does that linked answer not solve your problem?

Comment: @DanielRoseman there the models are in the same app so I'm confused as to what's what.