# Django Foreign Key to Multiple Models

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to make one model be able to foreignkey to more than one model?
For example

```
class Tshirt(models.Model):
   .....
class Jeans(models.Model):
   .....
class Clothes(models.Model):
   item = ForeignKey(Tshirt and Jeans, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You can work with a [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey), but this is often considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to connect both the model jeans and shirt with cloth so you an connect like that I am afraid that's not possible which you are trying but you can connect both model like that

```
class Tshirt(models.Model):
   .....
class Jeans(models.Model):
   .....
class Clothes(models.Model):
   item_one = models.ForeignKey(Tshirt, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   item_two = model.ForeignKey(Jeans, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
   item = GenericForeignKey('item_one', 'item_two')
```

or the second way is connect the cloth with both the model

```
    class Tshirt(models.Model):
        cloth = models.ForeignKey(Clothes, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    class Jeans(models.Model):
        cloth = models.ForeignKey(Clothes, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    class Clothes(models.Model):
       ....
```

I know this is not the answer you were expecting but according to me this is the only ways two interconnect model

Comment: I think I will do your second way and have `clothes` return `self.objects.all()`
That should get me close enough to where I am trying to get to I think. **Thank you**.
Do you know of any way in Django Admin to make a link to the object?
So, if it was
`Clothes` returned `Tshirt` and `Jeans`  on its admin `list_display` you could click on _Tshirt_ and it would take you to the `Tshirt` object, not the `Clothes` `ForeignKey` of it if that makes any sense.

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832897/link-in-django-admin-to-foreign-key-object

Comment: or you can use list_editable to directly edit it

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. What I've done for one of my projects is as follows:

```
class GeneralCategory(models.Model):
    id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

class ModelTargetingGeneralCategory(models.Model):
    id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    flexibleTarget=models.ForeignKey(GeneralCategory, on_delete=models.SET(""))

class FirstModel(GeneralCategory):
    #Add whatever attributes specific to your First Model

class SecondModel(GeneralCategory):
    #Add whatever attributes specific to your First Model
```

This solution allows you to have really any kind of relationship you'd like target a whole category of other models but you'll need to treat the category like a super class.

I have the ID in `GeneralCategory` because the ID is how the other models will target them, so you don't want the seperate models in the category to create their own IDs and have duplicate possibilities. I've done this and it works pretty well. Obviously you can treat each model as its own still.